# Django filter objects F('duration') from now

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Examle(models.Model):
  date = models.DateTime(auto_add_now=True)
  duration = models.IntegerField(default=90) # days
```

And I want to filter it like so:

```
Example.objects.filter(date_lt=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=F('duration')))
```

Of course `timedelta` won't take F-object as valid parameter, but hope you got what I mean.

Comment: Which database backend do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `F` to `timedelta` but you can use it to make a calculation:

```
timedelta(days=1) * F('duration')
```

Alternatively, if you're on Django 2.x, try:

```
Example.objects.annotate(days_before_today=ExtractDay(datetime.today() - F('date'))\
    .filter(days_before_today__gte=F('duration'))
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it gives `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Invalid connector for timedelta: *.` error. But `timedelta(days=1) * 90` fine.

Comment: It works for me. As asked by @Endre, what database are you using?

Comment: for testing I'm using plain SQLite. But I'd like to use universal expression, or else I could just use raw sql expression to construct query

Comment: is 'duration' an integer field?

Comment: Yes, duration is `models.IntegerField(default=90)`

Comment: Seems this is an issue with the SQLite backend, because if works for databases you'd use in production, like postgreSQL. see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25287). So I can't figure any other way than doing a RawSQL query in the case of SQLite.

Comment: Seems like it. Well, for now I'm just filtering out records with python, but hope to optimize query in future

Comment: Why not stop using SQLite? It’s not meant for production anyway.

Comment: On production server I'm using MySQL, but on local server for development I'm using SQLite for it's simplicity and portability.

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't think it's the best option but in the end switched to `DurationField` like this:

```
class Examle(models.Model):
date = models.DateTime(auto_add_now=True)
duration = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(days=90)) # days
```

And used it like this:

```
Example.objects.filter(date_lt=datetime.now() - F('duration'))
```

Comment: avoid using `datetime.now()`. use django's `timezone.now()` instead